# Clarification about name of father on baptism v birth. and location of father as solider in 1920?

Tags: england, birth-records, baptism-records, 1920s, sussex

I have been researching one of my wife's uncles (her grandfathers youngest brother. I received his birth certificate in the post today:

[image]

The above confirms that her grandfather did have a third sibling. Now, here is the baptism entry:

[image]

We know it is the right entry because of the address being 11 Washington. Now, I am not surprised that his father was not listed here because he was an active soldier and must have been away somewhere at the time of his birth in Brighton. But it is the fact that the father on the baptism is listed as William Alfred.

As you can see from the tree that I have so far:

[image]

My wife's grandfather was William Alfred but he would have been 6 in 1920. So I wondered if it might have been George's Grandfather - Alfred. I guess we won't know.

I wondered if you had any thoughts about this name on the baptism compared to the birth. And, if you have any thoughts about where his father William Harry would have been in his regiment in 1920 (I know he was listed in Ireland in the 1921 Census).

Comment: I would not get too hung up on the wrong second 'first name' on the baptism entry given the fathers occupation is the same on both and the first first name is the same. The informant on the birth certificate may have got the fathers second name wrong likewise the vicar could have misheard it or written it incorrectly. Or there could be other reasons that you don't yet know.

Comment: 'Arry or Alfred - there's not that much difference in the sound. Everything else is the same, as Colin says. And the father being elsewhere should have zero bearing on his name being on the baptism. After all, it documents the parents not (say) the godparents (who would need to be there since they make a commitment during the service.)

Comment: @Colin The birth is right. We have 3 birth certificates, 2 baptism records, and some marriage / census. William Harry is the father on all.

Comment: @AdrianB38 Thanks for comments.